# I try to install httplib on my python but I am getting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation, httplib

```
$ pip install httplib

Collecting httplib

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httplib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for httplib
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you using Python3?

The `httplib` module has been renamed to [http.client](http://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) in Python3